# Proper add, load and save node with delphi XE8 and VirtualStringTree

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I am using a virtualstringtree for basic treeview functionality with checkboxes, etc.
I used the original documentation (from 2006) but I am getting errors on loading the data that I save, even though the virtual string tree looks ok.

I believe that I should be using the `InitNode` rather than the `MAddVSTStructure`.

Can anyone suggest the proper way to add a node in this context?
That is possibly why the load procedures loads information but I get access violations on clicking the nodes that are loaded.

```
type
   PTreeData = ^TTreeData;
   TTreeData = record
      FCaption: String;
      FRichText: String;
      FImageIndex: integer;
      FVisibility: integer;
      FUniqueID: integer;
   end;

function MAddVSTStructure(AVST: TCustomVirtualStringTree; ANode: PVirtualNode;  ARecord: TTreeData): PVirtualNode;
var
   Data: PTreeData;
begin
   Result:= AVST.AddChild(ANode);
   Result.CheckType:=ctTriStateCheckBox;
   Data:= AVST.GetNodeData(Result);
   Data^.FCaption:= ARecord.FCaption;
   Data^.FRichText:= ARecord.FRichText;
   Data^.FImageIndex:= ARecord.FImageIndex;
   Data^.FVisibility:= ARecord.FVisibility;
   Data^.FUniqueID:= ARecord.FUniqueID;
   AVST.ValidateNode(Result, False);
end;    

procedure vstSaveNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode; Stream: TStream);
var
   Data: PTreeData;
   Len: integer;
begin
   Data:= Sender.GetNodeData(Node);

   //FCaption
   Len:= Length(Data.FCaption);
   Stream.Write(Len, SizeOf(Len));
   Stream.Write(PChar(Data.FCaption)^, Len * SizeOf(Char));

   //FRichText
   Len:= Length(Data.FRichText);
   Stream.Write(Len, SizeOf(Len));
   Stream.Write(PChar(Data.FRichText)^, Len * SizeOf(Char));

   //FImageIndex
   Stream.Write(Data.FImageIndex, SizeOf(Data.FImageIndex));

   //FVisibility
   Stream.Write(Data.FVisibility, SizeOf(Data.FVisibility));

   //FUniqueID
   Stream.Write(Data.FUniqueID, SizeOf(Data.FUniqueID));

end;
procedure vstLoadNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode; Stream: TStream);
var
   Data: PTreeData;
   Len: Integer;
begin
   Data:= Sender.GetNodeData(Node);
   //Len:= Length(Data.FCaption);

   //FCaption
   Stream.Read(Len, SizeOf(Len));
   SetLength(Data.FCaption, Len);
   Stream.Read(PChar(Data.FCaption)^, Len * SizeOf(Char) );

   //FRichText
   Stream.Read(Len, SizeOf(Len));
   SetLength(Data.FRichText, Len);
   Stream.Read(PChar(Data.FRichText)^, Len * SizeOf(Char));

   //FImageIndex
   Stream.Read(PChar(Data.FImageIndex)^, SizeOf(Data.FImageIndex));

   //FVisibility
   Stream.Read(PChar(Data.FVisibility)^, SizeOf(Data.FVisibility));

   //FUniqueID
   Stream.Read(PChar(Data.FUniqueID)^, SizeOf(Data.FUniqueID));

end;
```

Comment: Never say `I am getting errors` Always explain **exactly** which error you are getting, when, how, what time, what you were doing, etc etc. It is the most important thing to adhere to if you want people to be able to answer your question.